# Изменить цвет символов в textbox'e

Tags: c#, winforms

Каким образом поменять цвет в textboxe'e лишь отдельных слов и символов , а не в целом?

Comment: А за что минус? Нормальный вопрос, кстати.

Comment: @VladD по нескольким причинам: 1. В очередной раз отсутствуют попытки разобраться в проблеме прежде чем задать вопрос. 2. Частая "нулевая" реакция на ответы пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox` не поддерживает форматирование отдельных элементов текста.

Если нужно форматирование - используйте `RichTextBox`, который умеет работать с форматированием и поддерживает RTF-разметку. Примеры использования форматирования в `RichTextBox` есть в описании этого класса в [**официальной документации MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B).

Answer (score 1):

В поддержку правильного ответа @rdorn, вот вам код:

```
RichTextBox rtb = ...;
rtb.Text = "Красный синий зелёный";
rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
rtb.SelectionLength = 7;
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
rtb.SelectionStart = 8;
rtb.SelectionLength = 5;
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
rtb.SelectionStart = 14;
rtb.SelectionLength = 7;
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
rtb.SelectionStart = 0;
rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Результат:

[image: картинка]